# Unit Testing Xamarin Essentials

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

How to Unit Test the value of `Preference.Set("AppVersion","1.0")` in Xamarin forms ?

Tried `Assert.Equals(Preferences.Get("AppVersion", string.Empty), "1.0");` but getting Xamarin.Essentials.Notimplementedinreferenceassemblyexception

Comment: You'll need to create your own interface and class that wraps preferences. Then you can use DI to inject a mockup or to assert calls.

Comment: The reason might be that the Preferences API is implemented differently on each platform (Android, iOS, UWP) but not implemented at all for regular .NET apps (see the [Preferences API .NET Standard implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Preferences/Preferences.netstandard.cs) for reference). As @Andrew said, you'll need to mock it if you want to unit test code that uses Preferences.